# Java Spring-boot read pdf from classpath

Tags: java, spring-boot, pdf, byte

iam reading file from classpath config/sample-real.pdf, real size of file is 106 041 bytes, but when i run the same code in one spring boot app v2.4.3 it content length is good 106 041 bytes but on the other spring boot app v2.3.2.RELEASE it return contentlength = 149372 bytes and the pdf is corrupted when return to ResponseEntity<byte[]>

iam posting the code which working on one app and the same not working on the other.

```
public ResponseEntity<byte[]> generatePdf(String uid) throws IOException {
ClassPathResource file2 = new ClassPathResource("config/sample-real.pdf");

long lengthFile2 = file2.contentLength();//length here is corruputed 149372 instead of 106041
byte[] byteArr = IOUtils.toByteArray(file2.getInputStream());

HttpHeaders responseHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
responseHeaders
    .put("Content-Disposition", Collections.singletonList("attachment; filename=sample.pdf"));

return ResponseEntity.ok()
    .headers(responseHeaders)
    .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_PDF)
    .contentLength(byteArr.length)
    .body(byteArr);
```

}

working sample has spring-core:5.3.4, other spring boot app which does not work with this code is spring-core:5.2.8.RELEASE  - i tried to have the same spring-core but it does not work either.

**UPDATE**
ive got update, reading from classpath return corruput pdf, reading from file C://sample-real.pdf returning good content

```
File f ile1= new File("C:\\sample-real.pdf");
byte[] fileContent = Files.readAllBytes(file1.toPath());   //good 106k bytes

File resource = new ClassPathResource("config/sample-real.pdf").getFile();
byte[] fileContent2 = Files.readAllBytes(resource.toPath());  //bad 146k bytes
```

c:sample-real.pdf has size = 103 KB (106 041 bytes) and config/sample-real.pdf the same!

**UPDATE2**:
On jar there are corrputed length of 146k bytes when i made clean install

**SOLUTION**
files got corrupted because `<filtering>false</filtering>` in pom

```
  <build>
    <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>
    <resources>
      <resource>
        <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
        <filtering>false</filtering> //this WAS TRUE! i will need to check why, thanks everyone
        <excludes>
          <exclude>**/*.jks</exclude>
        </excludes>
      </resource>
      <resource>
        <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
        <filtering>false</filtering>
        <includes>
          <include>**/*.jks</include>
        </includes>
      </resource>
    </resources>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
```

Answer (score 0):

Update your `spring-boot` and `spring-framework`.

While we're lacking the minimal reproducing error code, reasons for not upgrading spring and actual error messages there's no way to tell the actual reason behind the "corruption".

Comment: @user2859429: have you manually inspected the produced jar files to see if the resource in the finally built jar is already corrupted? It's possible that your build applies some transformation.

Comment: @JoachimSauer youve got right, on jar there are corrupted filesize 146k bytes

Comment: @user2859429: then the culprit is most likely the build system: something is probably processing your PDF file, assuming it's text or something like that. Your code is probably not the issue.

Answer (score 0):

As the "filter" of the resources enable variable sostitution, the pom you have was correct (see https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/filter.html).

As you can see, you have two resource section (for the same folder), one with filtering enabled and the other with filtering disabled.

The most correct answer shoulbe to add **/*.pdf to the exclude list of the first resource tag and to the include list of the second include tag.

```
<build>
<finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>
<resources>
  <resource>
    <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
    <filtering>true</filtering> //this SHOULD BE TRUE to enable variable sostitution
    <excludes>
      <exclude>**/*.jks</exclude>
      <exclude>**/*.pdf</exclude> //added pdf to exclude list
    </excludes>
  </resource>
  <resource>
    <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
    <filtering>false</filtering>
    <includes>
      <include>**/*.jks</include>
      <include>**/*.pdf</include> //added pdf to include list
    </includes>
  </resource>
</resources>
<plugins>
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  </plugin>
</plugins>
```